What is the minimum requirement for a user to effectively use sys.crypt_properties to determine if a module is signed?
I am signing stored procedures using certificates.
Inside the stored procedure what is the minimum requirement needed to determine whether the running module is signed?
If not signed, I would like to quickly show an error message and exit the module or SP.
The same question asked a different way:-
execute as user='lowprivilege'

select *

from   sys.crypt_properties

revert;

will return an empty record set for a low privilege user;
For myself, returned a full list.
Here is a sample Stored Procedure.
Please try again making sure to add ( Execute as caller ).
Otherwise, you are running as sp creator.

if object_id('dbo.usp_signedObject') is null
begin

   exec('create procedure dbo.usp_signedObject as ')    
    
end
go

alter procedure [dbo].[usp_signedObject]

WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
begin

    set nocount on;

    select 

              [schema] = tblSS.[name]

            , [object] = tblSO.[name]

            , [objectType] = tblSO.[type]

            , [objectTypeDescription] = tblSO.[type_desc]

            , tblSCP.crypt_type

            , tblSCP.crypt_type_desc

            , [certificate] = tblSC.[name]

      from   sys.objects tblSO

      INNER JOIN sys.schemas tblSS

            on tblSO.schema_id = tblSS.schema_id

      INNER JOIN sys.crypt_properties tblSCP

            on  tblSO.[object_id] = tblSCP.major_id

            and tblSCP.class = 1

     LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.certificates tblSC

            ON  tblSC.thumbprint = tblSCP.thumbprint 


    
end
go


grant execute on dbo.usp_signedObject to [public]
go



"will return an empty record set for a low privilege user" is that true even if they have EXECUTE permissions on one of its procedures or functions?

You could try this in the procedure body:
if exists 
(
    select 1
    from sys.procedures pro 
        inner join sys.crypt_properties cry on cry.major_id = pro.object_id 
        inner join sys.certificates cer on cer.thumbprint = cry.thumbprint 
    where object_name(@@PROCID) = pro.name
) 
begin
    print('I''m signed')
end


I think it depends on user running the SP.
I added "WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER".
Thank you very much.

Erland Sommarskog answers the question here:-
What is the minimum level of permission that is required to effectively determine if an object is signed using sys.crypt_properties?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1639329/what-is-the-minimum-level-of-permission-that-is-re
